# How can I clear the entire activity feed in github (entries under Browse Activity Tab)?

Tags: github

The question is as stated in the title.

Answer (score 3):

This used to bother me too, I assumed that it was not possible, well maybe if you unsubscribe from everything but haven't tried that. A similar question has been asked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20738/how-do-i-delete-entries-from-my-github-activity-feed) which further confirms that GitHub has not made that possible, but maybe if you email them and ask they will delete it for you.